# Connecting to a publically Exposed Soap Service Through WSO2 ESB and API Manager in WSO2

Tags: soap, wso2, integration, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

i m working on a scenario 'connecting to Backend service with Simple SOAP binding' required to expose as a RESTful using WSO2 ESB and API manager .
Api Manager is a essential in my scenario so can't ignore it.

I Have configured both but facing some issues in Authentication .

below is the error log describing the problem.

```
 [2015-10-06 18:10:59,721] ERROR - APIUtil Unauthorized client domain :null. Only


"[]" domains are authorized to access the API.
[2015-10-06 18:10:59,727] ERROR - AbstractKeyValidationHandler Error while valid
ating client domain

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Unauthorized client domain :n
ull. Only "[]" domains are authorized to access the API.
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.checkClientDomainAuthorized
(APIUtil.java:3916)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.AbstractKeyValidationHandler.c
heckClientDomainAuthorized(AbstractKeyValidationHandler.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.AbstractKeyValidationHandler.v
alidateSubscription(AbstractKeyValidationHandler.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validat
eKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:157)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceI
mpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:131)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$
Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:278)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$
Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:266)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadP
oolServer.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[2015-10-06 18:10:59,749] ERROR - APIUtil Unauthorized client domain :null. Only
 "[]" domains are authorized to access the API.
[2015-10-06 18:10:59,750]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication fa
ilure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure
```

.

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Note That i m using a simple publically available Soap service for scenario.

Comment: Can you please format your error properly. It's not readable. Copy the trace here and use the code editor to format

Answer (score 0):

This is happen maybe because your token is expired. So set the below value on identity.xml

```
AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod to -1
```

and restart the server

for more information read
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API#TokenAPI-Configuringthetokenexpirationtime

Comment: Thatz not a case in this scenario i have already set it to -1.

Comment: do you have a secondary user store?